# How to send multiple parallel request at a time using radclient

Tags: radius

I have tried using below command, where `-p <num_requests_in_parallel>`, is supposed to send 5 requests at a time but it is not happening; could anyone please let me know what is missing here?

```
radclient -f radius.txt -p 5 -x 172.16.10.135 auth testing123
```

After sending the request on terminal i can see how many request are being sent. See below for example:

```
/home/radius_test>radclient -f radius.txt -n 5 172.16.10.135 auth testing123
Sent Access-Request Id 155
from 0.0.0.0:42282 to 10.239.27.180:1812 length 207
Received Access-Accept Id 155
from 10.239.27.180:1812 to 0.0.0.0:0 length 52
```

Also i am maintaining a table, in which i am storing the number of requests coming on radius server

Comment: Exactly what output are you getting? How do you know it isn't sending the requests in parallel?

Comment: After sending the request on terminal i can see how many request are being sent. See below for example /home/radius_test>radclient -f radius.txt -p 5 172.16.10.135 auth testing123 Sent Access-Request Id 155 from 0.0.0.0:42282 to 10.239.27.180:1812 length 207 Received Access-Accept Id 155 from 10.239.27.180:1812 to 0.0.0.0:0 length 52.

 Also I am maintaining a table, in which i am storing the number of requests coming on radius server